# Dynamic Global Variables

Tags: laravel

I am new in web development and using laravel framework for my 1st project.  I am trying to define a dynamic global variable.

My problem is as under :
I want to setup two types of app users.  One that are fixed to a specific branch and second who will select a branch.  I have added a branch_id column to my users table and its working properly.  Zero in this column means the user will select his branch after login.  What I want is to store branch_id to a global variable that can be accessed everywhere (controllers, views, etc.).
I have tried to use Config but the new value is available only in current code block.

{{ Config::set('pubvar.lbranch','Testing') }}

{{ config('pubvar.lbranch') }}

I need assistance regarding this in a simple possible way.  Sample code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Session` or `Cookie` to save global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the variable is login dependent, the easiest solution is using [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session). The easiest way to set it is in the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`. Add a function like this which overrides the original from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    session('pubvar.lbranch','Testing');
}
```

Anywhere in your code, controllers, views and even models alike just call:

```
$branch = session('pubvar.lbranch');
```

or in views

```
{{ session('pubvar.lbranch') }}
```

If there is no value, calling the `session()` helper will result in `null`.

Comment: I need to open a branch selection view for users with branch_id=0
In this view pubvar.lbranch value will be set.
The code to open view if branch_id=0 will go in ?

Comment: I am getting this error (using laravel 5.8) :
"Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate

Answer (score 0):

Laravel view composer may help you. 
You should add this code to your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php.

```
view()->composer(['lbranch'], function($view) {
        $branch_id = auth()->user()->branch_id;
        $view->with([
            'brach_id' => $branch_id
        ]);
    });
```

or you can simply use:

```
{{ auth()->user()->branch_id }}
```

Comment: I need to open a branch selection view for users with branch_id=0
In this view pubvar.lbranch value will be set.
The code to open view if branch_id=0 will go in ?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed in your controller you can check auth()->user()->branch_id with if condition and if this is equal with zero open your view